# C++ splitting string?

Tags: c++, string, split

I've been dealing with C++ strings and currently I am wondering how can I split the ***article*** of a string and the data that's left.

Let's say I have this string:

```
a gold coin
```

How can I split the ***article*** which in this case is ***a*** into a separate string and then get all the other data contents into a different string which in this case is ***gold coin***?

Please note that the article can sometimes be ***an*** and sometimes have no article.

***Edit***
I am not trying to split strings from a space token I am splitting special words from the string in condition for extracting a pronoun article name and the pronoun string.

Comment: Will you always have a simple `[article] [nouns]` layout or do you need to parse complex sentences?

Comment: I would love to write an answer but I updated my system and it borked everything.  Look into std::string::substr().  You could check for mystring.substr( 0, 3 ) == "an " || mystring.substr( 0, 2 ) == "a ".  If you match either, mystring.substr( 4 ) in the first case of mystring.substr( 3 ) in the 2nd case should give you the rest of the string.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: the linked question goes over strategies on how to use `substr`, `replace`, etc to split a string.

Comment: No problem!  Any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> **.replace**

```
str.replace(str.begin()+1,str.end()1,1,'');
```

[the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

Comment: I assumed the OP wants two resultant strings.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be:

1. find the end of the first word: `std::string maybe_article = input.substr(0, input.find_first_of(" \t"));`
2. check if it's an article: `if (maybe_article == "a" or maybe_article == "the" or maybe_article == "the")`
3. if so, take the substring. `return input.substring(input.substr(input.find_first_not_of(" \t", maybe_article.size())));`
4. otherwise, return just the original string. `return input;`

It's possible to avoid the allocation of `maybe_article`, but if you're restricting yourself to the standard library this is the most obvious way, and is easily modified to support a count in place of the article.

Personally I gave up on `std::string` and wrote my own.